# What's the error since s is string not character?

Tags: arrays, c, string, compiler-errors, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string replace(string s);

int main(void/*int argc, string argv[]*/)
//int main(string)
{
printf("%s\n", replace);
//return 0;
}

string replace(string s)
{
    //string s;
    int n;
    s = get_string("Please type the word: ");
    //s = tolower(s[i]);
    n = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        switch(tolower(s[i]))
        {
            case 'a' :
            s[i] = '6';
            continue;
            case 'e' :
            s[i] = '3';
            continue;
            case 'i' :
            s[i] = '1';
            continue;
            case 'o' :
            s[i] = '0';
            continue;
            case 'u' :
            s[i] = 'u';
            continue;
            //default :
            //printf("default");
        }
    }
    return s;
    //printf("%c\n", s[0]);
    //n = strlen(s);
    //printf("%i\n",n);
    //printf("%s\n", s);
    //printf("%s\n", s);
    //return 1;
}
```

getting vowels replaced by numbers. Code gives me error as if s is character. What is the fix for this?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good start for gcc and clang)

Comment: The symbol `replace` is a function. To use it you need to *call* it. You don't call it. you let it decay to a pointer and the use that pointer as a null-terminated string. Which it isn't, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why are you using `continue` instead of `break` in a switch case?

Comment: All in all, it seems like you need to take a few steps back and refresh some of the really basics of C.

Comment: What does "Code gives me error" mean? Did you get an error message from the compiler? If so, include that error message in your question (formatted as code).

Comment: `string` is a typedef in the non-standard header `<cs50.h>`. As I recall, it's `typedef char *string;`. (Strings are not pointers in C, so the name `string` is misleading.)

Comment: Error from compiler: format specifies type char but the argument has type string. Note that the function itself as a standalone is working just fine. @KeithThompson

Comment: I agree with @KeithThompson. The cs50 library goes out of its way to befuddle new C programmers, and the magic `string` object it creates obfuscates some very basic conceptual ideas newbies need to grasp right at the beginning, IMNSHO.

Comment: @faf: That is essential information that should be inside the question itself. Please [edit] the question to add it. Also, if the compiler error message is referring to a specific line or line number, then please add this information, too.

Comment: @faf No, please include the exact error message in the question itself. Copy-and-paste the error message (don't re-type it), and format it as code.

Comment: CS50 is already widely known as a very bad class for learning C programming so we needn't beat the dead horse here. Just avoid learning material from Harvard uni and read a book instead.

Comment: In contrast to the comments that some other people wrote, I highly recommend CS50. In week 4 of CS50, the students learn what a pointer is. In that lesson, they also learn the true nature of the `string` data type.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, you have not *called* `replace` in `main`. You are simply passing the function itself to `printf` which decays to a pointer which almost certainly should not be treated as a string by `printf`. Cue undefined behavior.

You have `replace` taking a `string` argument, but then immediately ignoring that passed in `char*`. The argument serves no purpose and should be eliminated to leave `string replace(void)`.

Assumign we edit `replace` to not take the extraneous argument, `main` should look something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", replace());
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it would probably be *better* design for `main` to prompt for an input string, pass it to `replace` and have `replace` modify that string or return a modified version of it which `main` can then print.